# Shared Element Transition is not exiting properly

Tags: java, android, android-animation, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

I have fragment from which I'm launching activity with shared element transition that has viewpager in it, the enter transition works fine but when i scroll in view pager and finish transition the shared image comes from left side which is not desired it should reposition itself to where it was launched, here is my code:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), EnlargeActivity.class);

            ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
                    makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity(),
                            imageView,
                            ViewCompat.getTransitionName(imageView));
            startActivity(myIntent, options.toBundle());
```

I'm updating view and its name in activity that contains viewpager when finishing activity, but its going with blink:

```
public void finishAfterTransition() {
    setEnterSharedElementCallback(new SharedElementCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapSharedElements(List<String> names, Map<String, View> sharedElements) {
            // Clear all current shared views and names
            names.clear();
            sharedElements.clear();

            ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) viewPagerDetail.getAdapter()
                    .instantiateItem(viewPagerDetail, viewPagerDetail.getCurrentItem());

            if (viewGroup == null) {
                return;
            }

            // Map the first shared element name to the child ImageView.
            sharedElements.put(viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.img).getTransitionName(), viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.img));

           // setExitSharedElementCallback((SharedElementCallback) this);
        }
    });

    super.finishAfterTransition();
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically, Android start the transition with your pre-defined `View` and `transitionName` and automatically use the same properties for the return transition. When you change your focused View in ViewPager, Android doesn't know about that and keep the transition on the previous one on its way back. So you need to inform Android about the changes:

- Remap the transition properties: Use `setEnterSharedElementCallback` to change the `transitionName` and `View` to the new one before returning from `Activity2`.
- Wait for the `Activity1` to finish rendering `addOnPreDrawListener`.

It's a bit complex in the final implementation. But you can look at my sample code https://github.com/tamhuynhit/PhotoGallery. I try to implement the shared-element-transition from many simple to complex sections.
Your problem appeared from `Level 3` and solved in `Level 4`.

I am writing a tutorial about this but it's not in English so hope the code can help

**UPDATE 1: Work flow**

Here is how I implement it in my code:

- Override `finishAfterTransition` in Activity2 and call `setEnterSharedElementCallback` method to re-map the current selected item in ViewPager. Also, call `setResult` to pass the new selected index back to previous activity here.

  ```
  @Override 
  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) 
  public void finishAfterTransition() {
      setEnterSharedElementCallback(new SharedElementCallback() {
          @Override
          public void onMapSharedElements(List<String> names, Map<String, View> sharedElements) {
              View selectedView = getSelectedView();
              if (selectedView == null)
                  return;

              // Clear all current shared views and names
              names.clear();
              sharedElements.clear();

              // Store new selected view and name
              String transitionName = ViewCompat.getTransitionName(selectedView);
              names.add(transitionName);
              sharedElements.put(transitionName, selectedView);

              setExitSharedElementCallback((SharedElementCallback) null);
          }
      });

      Intent intent = new Intent();
      intent.putExtra(PHOTO_FOCUSED_INDEX, mCurrentIndex);
      setResult(RESULT_PHOTO_CLOSED, intent);

      super.finishAfterTransition();
  }
  ```
- Write a custom `ShareElementCallback` so I can set the callback before knowing which `View` is going to be used.

  ```
  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
  private static class CustomSharedElementCallback extends SharedElementCallback {
      private View mView;

      /**
       * Set the transtion View to the callback, this should be called before starting the transition so the View is not null
       */
      public void setView(View view) {
          mView = view;
      }

      @Override
      public void onMapSharedElements(List<String> names, Map<String, View> sharedElements) {
          // Clear all current shared views and names
          names.clear();
          sharedElements.clear();

          // Store new selected view and name
          String transitionName = ViewCompat.getTransitionName(mView);
          names.add(transitionName);
          sharedElements.put(transitionName, mView);
      }
  }
  ```
- Override `onActivityReenter` in Activity1, get the selected index from the result `Intent`. Set `setExitSharedElementCallback` to re-map new selected `View` when the transition begins.Call `supportPostponeEnterTransition` to delay a bit because your new `View` may not be rendered at this point. Use `getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener` to listen for the layout changes, find the right `View` by the selected index and continue the transition `supportStartPostponedEnterTransition`.

  ```
  @Override
  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
  public void onActivityReenter(int resultCode, Intent data) {
      if (resultCode != LevelFourFullPhotoActivity.RESULT_PHOTO_CLOSED || data == null)
          return;

      final int selectedIndex = data.getIntExtra(LevelFourFullPhotoActivity.PHOTO_FOCUSED_INDEX, -1);
      if (selectedIndex == -1)
          return;

      // Scroll to the new selected view in case it's not currently visible on the screen
      mPhotoList.scrollToPosition(selectedIndex);

      final CustomSharedElementCallback callback = new CustomSharedElementCallback();
      getActivity().setExitSharedElementCallback(callback);

      // Listen for the transition end and clear all registered callback
      getActivity().getWindow().getSharedElementExitTransition().addListener(new Transition.TransitionListener() {
          @Override
          public void onTransitionStart(Transition transition) {}

          @Override
          public void onTransitionPause(Transition transition) {}

          @Override
          public void onTransitionResume(Transition transition) {}

          @Override
          public void onTransitionEnd(Transition transition) {
              removeCallback();
          }

          @Override
          public void onTransitionCancel(Transition transition) {
              removeCallback();
          }

          private void removeCallback() {
              if (getActivity() != null) {
                  getActivity().getWindow().getSharedElementExitTransition().removeListener(this);
                  getActivity().setExitSharedElementCallback((SharedElementCallback) null);
              }
          }
      });

      // Pause transition until the selected view is fully drawn
      getActivity().supportPostponeEnterTransition();

      // Listen for the RecyclerView pre draw to make sure the selected view is visible,
      //  and findViewHolderForAdapterPosition will return a non null ViewHolder
      mPhotoList.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
          @Override
          public boolean onPreDraw() {
              mPhotoList.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);

              RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = mPhotoList.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(selectedIndex);
              if (holder instanceof ViewHolder) {
                  callback.setView(((ViewHolder) holder).mPhotoImg);
              }

              // Continue the transition
              getActivity().supportStartPostponedEnterTransition();

              return true;
          }
      });
  }
  ```

**UPDATE 2: getSelectedItem**

To get selected View from the ViewPager, don't use `getChildAt` or you get the wrong View, use `findViewWithTag` instead

In the `PagerAdapter.instantiateItem`, use position as tag for each View:

```
@Override
public View instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    // Create the View
    view.setTag(position)

    // ...
}
```

Listen to `onPageSelected` event to get the selected index:

```
mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        mSelectedIndex = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
});
```

Call `getSelectedView` to get the current view by the selected index

```
private View getSelectedView() {
    try {
        return mPhotoViewPager.findViewWithTag(mSelectedIndex);
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException | NullPointerException ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right transition name is not setting properly thats why problem happening, I'm tying your approach

Comment: where should apply setEnterSharedElementCallback

Comment: @blackHawk it's explained in the [same article](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/02/continuous-shared-element-transitions.html) that you read

Comment: @blackHawk I've added an update above in my answer to explain more about my code

Comment: @LieForBananas yes, trying to understand bit more,

Comment: @TamHuynh when onMapSharedElements will be called? actually i have fragment and through fragment im launching activity with shared element transition that has viewpager in it,

Comment: @LieForBananas I'm getting out of way properly set transition name because viewpager's instantiate item called 3 times and transition name got disturb

Comment: @blackHawk it's called 3 times probably because ViewPager is preloading the pages for performance reasons

Comment: where i use onMapSharedElements, or i need not to use

Comment: @TamHuynh I tried, but i cant access view to get its transition name because its in Viewpage adapter not in activity

Comment: `onMapSharedElements` will be called on both Activities when enter/ exit the transition. That's why we need to set the callback back to null right after finishing the work so it won't mess up the next transition. 

Shared element from Fragment to Activity is the same as Activity to activity because fragment can access its Activity by `getActivity()`. You just need to pass the call from `onActivityReenter` to the fragment.

I will update the answer to include the ViewPager current view selection.

Comment: Uncomment the last line: `setEnterSharedElementCallback(null)` is important. And did you setup `onActivityReenter` in the first Activity? The remap process needs to be done on both sides

Comment: where onActivityReenter? in fragment?

Comment: It's in `Activity` only, it's called when Activity2 is finished to get back on Activity1 but before the transition, write your own `onActivityReenter` in the fragment and call it from Activity. The implementation is shared above

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a default behavior, I was struggling SharedElementTransitions a lot, but I have nested fragments. I got my solution from an article (very recent article), it shows an implementation with a `RecyclerView`, which I assume you have. In short, the solution is to override `onLayoutChange` :

```
recyclerView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(
new OnLayoutChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void onLayoutChange(View view,
            int left, 
            int top, 
            int right, 
            int bottom, 
            int oldLeft, 
            int oldTop, 
            int oldRight, 
            int oldBottom) {
     recyclerView.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);
     final RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager =
        recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
     View viewAtPosition = 
        layoutManager.findViewByPosition(MainActivity.currentPosition);
     // Scroll to position if the view for the current position is null (not   
     // currently part of layout manager children), or it's not completely
     // visible.
     if (viewAtPosition == null 
         || layoutManager.isViewPartiallyVisible(viewAtPosition, false, true)){
        recyclerView.post(() 
           -> layoutManager.scrollToPosition(MainActivity.currentPosition));
     }
 }
});
```

Here is the [article](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/02/continuous-shared-element-transitions.html), and you will also find the project on [GitHub](https://github.com/google/android-transition-examples/tree/master/GridToPager).

Comment: I used the same article and i learnt alot from it, but here is different situation, I'm opening activity with shared element from fragment, when i finish that activity it works fine, but when i add viewpager in activity and then finish activity its behaving like transition name is not set properly, it comes from right hand side where as when there is no viewpager the image comes straight like zoom in and goes back like zoom out which is desired

Comment: can you figure out whats being happening when im adding viewpager in activity and finishing activity

Comment: @blackHawk So if you have the viewpager, open the activity, and close it without swiping the viewpager it still does the same?

Comment: adding viewpager in activity causing difference, no matter i swap or not

Comment: @blackHawk as you said, it may be due to transition names, what does your viewpager contain? Are you sure that the names are unique? I had a problem with [conflicting transition names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49806441/shared-element-transition-fragment-recyclerview-viewpager), I was using a tablayout with fragments that were displaying similar data, so I had to add fragment numbers to my transition names to differentiate them.

Comment: in instantiateitem of viewpager im doing like this:  img.setTransitionName("simple_activity_transition");

Comment: @blackHawk Are you using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`? It's probably because your transition name is the same for all viewpager pages, try appending the position when you are setting transition name, like this `img.setTransitionName("simple_activity_transition" + position)`

Comment: I have noticed, suppose i have 5 in getCount of viewpager, when i scrolled to 5th item and then exit activity it works fine, and when i scroll to 3 or 4 it does not work

Comment: img.setTransitionName("simple_activity_transition" + position) does work but it it coming or going with blink

Comment: @blackHawk it's good it's working :) the whole image is blinking or the status bar and action bar?

Comment: whole image is blinking

Comment: @blackHawk I believe it's a common problem, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28591442/7915814) it should help, it has to do with activities animating in and out.

Comment: I think problem still lies in transition name, Im unable to assign unique name for each image

Comment: @blackHawk I thought you said it's working when you append the position? If not then you have to think about creating unique names, in my case I was using image paths as transition names, maybe you can do the same, maybe pass the image path to the constructor and add it as a transition name.

Comment: I did the same for my previous work :) for this unfortunately(for the time being) I have only one url, what about connect personally? I really like talking to you, you understand better :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170426/discussion-between-lieforbananas-and-blackhawk).

Comment: I believe what this code snippet does is to just scroll the recyclerview to ensure that the currently displayed view from the viewpager is visible when the user decides to go back to the recyclerview. It has nothing to do with transitions